# Have I found my harmonic function correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry, boundary-value-problem, mobius-transformation

The problem statement is:

Use conformal mapping to find a harmonic function $U(z)$ defined on the unit disc $∣z∣<1$ such that

$$\lim_{r→1} U(re^{iθ})
= \left\{\begin{aligned}
&+1 &&: 0<\theta<\pi\\
&-1 &&: \pi<\theta<2\pi
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Give the correct determination of any multiple-valued functions appearing in your answer.

How is my work?

First, I took the mapping $w= \large \frac{z-i}{z+i}$, and solved for z.

Now I have a mapping from the unit disk to the UHP.  The mapping is

$$ h := \frac {-i(1+w)}{w-1}$$

Then arg(h) is 0 on $R^+$, which happens to be the image of the *lower* semi-circle, and arg(h) = $\pi$ on $R^-$, which is the image of the upper semi-circle.

And finally take $ cos(arg(h))$ gives -1 on the upper semi-circle and +1 on the lower semi-circle, so we negate this function to get

$$\Gamma:= -cos(arg(h)),$$
$$=  -cos(arg(\frac {-i(1+w)}{w-1}))$$

which gives us what we want.

We note that both the arg and cosine functions are harmonic, since cosine is the real part of $e^{i\theta}$ and arg(z) is the imaginary part of log(z) (say, cutting away the negative imaginary axis.)

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: it's not hard to find a harmonic function on the upper half plane  with boundary values $+1$ on one side of the $x$ axis and $-1$ on the other.   Find a conformal map of that to the disk...

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael, since $e^{i\theta}$ is analytic, then its real and imaginary parts are harmonic conjugates.  So I can consider the harmonic function cos($\theta$), and then $cos(arg(R^+))$ = $cos(0)$ = +1 and $cos(arg(R^-))$ = cos($\pi$) = -1.  Am I on the right track?  And a standard LFT from the UHP to the unit disk would be $\large w = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$.  However, I am a little confused about how to compose the two functions...

Comment: Actually, I think  I might have it now:  I took the mapping w= z-i/z+i, and solved for z.  Now I have a mapping from the unit disk to the UHP.  The mapping is h= -i(1+w) / (w-1).  Then arg(h) is 0 on $R^+$, which happens to be the image of the *lower* semi-circle, and $\pi$ on $R^-$, which is the image of the upper semi-circle.  And finally cos(arg(h)) gives -1 on the upper semi-circle and +1 on the lower semi-circle, so we negate this function to get -cos(arg(h)), which gives us what we want.  What do you think, Professor Israel?  Thanks and have a great night,

Comment: I also edited my question post to include my work.  Thanks @RobertIsrael :-)

Comment: I actually just thought up of another solution that I am more familiar with -- still mapping from the unit disk to the UHP first, then using just the arg(z) function, translating it by -$\large \frac{\pi}{2}$ and finally scaling this quantity $\large \frac{2}{\pi}$; this solution also gives the boundary values that I want, and arg(z) is harmonic and defined on the UHP, by restricting the argument between 0 and $2\pi$.

Comment: Do you think that there is anything wrong with the cosine mapping, though?  I have never used cosine before, but I don't see that there's anything wrong with it.  I think it's clearly harmonic, since it's the real part of an analytic function.  Thanks, Professor Israel.